# Bootstrap typeahead not working with my following code

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a code to search places. The server is returning the data in json format correctly but typeahead is not showing the results.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#txt_ser').typeahead({
      minLength:1,
      source: function (query, process) {
          var places = [];
          var map = {};
          $.ajax({
              dataType: "json",
              url: "<?php echo base_url() . "ajax/ser";?>",
              data: 'q='+query,
              type: 'POST',
              success: function (data) {
                  $.each(data, function(i, place){
                      map[place.yt_center_state] = place;
                      places.push(place.yt_center_state);
                  });
                  return process(places);
               }
          })
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Server is returning data in json format an example is shown below when keyword pune is typed

```
0: {yt_center_top_city:pune, yt_center_state:MH}
1: {yt_center_top_city:pune, yt_center_state:MH}
2: {yt_center_top_city:pune, yt_center_state:MH}
3: {yt_center_top_city:pune, yt_center_state:MH}
```

Comment: is there any error in the console? I've some doubts about syntax of `"<?php echo base_url() . "ajax/ser";?>"` but I'm not a PHP guy

Comment: Also is the ajax request sent to the sever and the success callback is geting called

Comment: no there is no error i have added the json data that is returned by the server with status code 200

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with PHP

Answer (score 0):

You didn't return the result of your ajax request to typeahead `source`. This line of your code:

```
 return process(places);
```

is inside `success` handler of `$.ajax`, so it only returns the `places` to that function.

You should change your code to:

```
$('#txt_ser').typeahead({
  minLength:1,
  source: function (query, process) {
      var places = [];
      var map = {};
      return $.ajax({   // <- add return here
          dataType: "json",
          url: "<?php echo base_url() . "ajax/ser";?>",
          data: 'q='+query,
          type: 'POST',
          success: function (data) {
              $.each(data, function(i, place){
                  map[place.yt_center_state] = place;
                  places.push(place.yt_center_state);
              });
              return process(places);
          }
      });
  }
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: No it's not working after changing the code also ... Server is sending the data in JSON format. This part of my site is really hurting me ...

Comment: Hmm if you do `console.log(places);` before `return process(places);`, can you see your expected `places`? Otherwise I guess the foreach loop has problem.

Comment: console.log is displaying result like ["MH", "MH", "MH", "MH"]

Comment: Then I'm sure that your issue is something else. Check my fiddle here with nearly identical data: http://jsfiddle.net/hieuh25/AT3SF/1/